# Implicit conversions with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

Consider two function calls

```
foo({"a", 1}, {"b", "value"});
foo({"a", 1}, {"b", "value"}, {"c", 1.0});
```

Is there a way to write function `foo` for arbitrary number of argument pairs?

I was thinking something along the lines

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(std::pair<const char*, Args>&&...);
```

which unfortunately does not work.

gcc fails with an error:

```
error: too many arguments to function 'void foo(std::pair<const char*, Args>&& ...) [with Args = {}]'
 foo({"aa", 1});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand a bit on [Edgar Rokyan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41069394/1116364), you can move the pair creation into the `foo` function:

```
template<typename... Args>
void foo() {}

// Forward declaration
template<typename U, typename... Args>
void foo(const char * str, U u, Args... args);

// When given a pair
template<typename U, typename... Args>
void foo(const std::pair<const char *, U>& p, Args... args) {
    std::cout << p.first << " = " << p.second << std::endl;
    foo(args...);
}

// when given a C string and something else, make a pair
template<typename U, typename... Args>
void foo(const char * str, U u, Args... args) {
    foo(std::make_pair(str, u), args...);
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
foo("hi", 42,
    "yo", true,
    std::make_pair("Eh", 3.14),
    "foo", false,
    some_pair);
```

Comment: Please remove the `template<typename...Args>` above the first overload declaration of `foo` (remove the first line). You do not call any foo<arg...>(), you just call foo(). Declaring the first empty foo overload as a template just bring confusion: it looks like there were a confusion between template specialization and overloading. In your code you declare three overload foo, but only one specialization of the first overload is used: foo<>(), so the first overload do not need to be a template.

Comment: Correction: "only one instantiation of the first overload is used:foo<>()"

Answer (score 8):

Try to simplify a bit your example and consider this:

```
#include<utility>

template<typename T>
void foo(std::pair<char*, T>) {}

int main() {
    foo({"a", 1});
}
```

It doesn't compile, [as you can see](https://godbolt.org/g/a8ELg6).
The problem is that `{ "a", 1 }` is not a `std::pair`, even if you can construct one from it as it follows:

```
#include<utility>

void foo(std::pair<char*, int>) {}

int main() {
    foo({"a", 1});
}
```

The error is quite clear:

> couldn't infer template argument 'T'

Why can't you?

Te compiler could construct such a pair once `T` is known. Anyway, `T` must be deduced and the compiler cannot do that because `{ "a", 1 }` is not a pair from which it can be deduced.
Anyway, `{ "a", 1 }` can be converted to a pair, in the specific case to a specialization of `std::pair<char *, T>`, but first of all `T` must be deduced.
Deduced from what? A pair, of course, but you don't have a pair yet.
And so on, in a loop.

Let's discuss now your attempt to do something similar that involves a variadic template: it goes without saying that, if even the simpler example shown above doesn't compile, its variadic extension (if any) would not compile as well for more or less the same reason.

> Is there a way to write function foo for arbitrary number of argument pairs?

I would say no, unless you use pairs as arguments for `foo`.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<utility>

template <typename... Args>
void foo(std::pair<const char*, Args>&&...) {}

int main() {
    foo(std::make_pair("a", 1), std::make_pair("b", "value"));
}
```

If you prefer, you can also deduce the first argument, as long as its type is fixed:

```
#include<utility>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void foo(std::pair<T, Args>&&...) {}

int main() {
    foo(std::make_pair("a", 1), std::make_pair("b", "value"));
}
```

Otherwise you can do this if it's not fixed:

```
#include<utility>

template <typename... First, typename... Second>
void foo(std::pair<First, Second>&&...) {}

int main() {
    foo(std::make_pair("a", 1), std::make_pair(0, "value"));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way to write function foo for arbitrary number of argument
>   pairs?

There are some solutions based on variadic templates but arguments **must be pairs** to allow compiler to deduce types. Then something like this might work:

```
template<typename... Args>
void foo() {}

template<typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
void foo(const std::pair<T, U>& p, Args... args) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    foo(args...);
}
```

So for:

```
foo(std::make_pair("a", 1), std::make_pair("b", "value"), std::make_pair("c", 1.0));
```

The output (with *clang 3.8*) is:

```
void foo(const std::pair<T, U> &, Args...) [T = const char *, U = int, Args = <std::__1::pair<const char *, const char *>, std::__1::pair<const char *, double>>]
void foo(const std::pair<T, U> &, Args...) [T = const char *, U = const char *, Args = <std::__1::pair<const char *, double>>]
void foo(const std::pair<T, U> &, Args...) [T = const char *, U = double, Args = <>]
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/g/aZ1LF6) is the full working example.

Comment: I have tested your code with clang 3.8, it does not compile. Whatsoever your code does not conform to the standard.

Comment: @Oliv I added the link to the answer. Now you can check the full code. Which part of the code does not conform to the standard?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`?

Comment: @skypjack hah, yeah, this is an extension, of course)

Comment: @EdgarRokyan Moreover, you don't have to get the pairs one at the time out of the pack. See the last snippet from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41069242/4987285). It is somehow similar to what the OP posted in the question.I think he's interested in the `Args`.

Comment: @skypjack I've already checked it and your solution is nice! Can we modify it somehow to avoid hardcoding the first type in these pairs as `const char*`?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan Updated my answer. Was that what you were asking for? See the last snippet.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan Added another snippet, in case the first parameter is not of a fixed type. ;-)

Comment: @EdgarRokyan I did not see the call with make_pair.

Answer (score 0):

In c++17 you may be able to workaround the problem and cheat compiler a bit by using template deduction of constructors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <class... Args>
struct P:std::pair<Args...> {
    P(Args... args):std::pair<Args...>(args...) { }
};

template <class... Args>
void foo(std::pair<const char *, Args>&&...) {
}

int main() {
    foo(P{"abc", 1}, P{"abc", "abc"}, P{"abc", 2.0});
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KLATuTq2R3f8U2uB)

Comment: If you can use deduction from constructors - you can write `foo(std::pair{"a", 1}/*...*/)`. If you don't want to write such a "long" name as `std::pair` - write `template<typename T1, typename T2> using P = std::pair<T1, T2>`. No need for this `struct P` stuff.

Comment: @Rostislav well maybe in c++17 it will work for now gcc does not allow it: [example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bVkVFq0kXpcbN1Bn)

Comment: That's quite interesting as to why this extra layer works fine for string literals, but direct `pair` construction doesn't (it seems to work fine for non-string-literals).

Comment: @Rostislav I wouldn't blame gcc as it does not fully support c++17 yet :)

Comment: Sure thing - it's just amazing how complex compilers are and which tricks can get some things to work :)

Comment: @Rostislav Class template argument deduction doesn't work with alias templates.